# How to select a directory in a non Windows-specific .NET 6.0 application?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, multiplatform

I want to present the user with a dialog that allows them to select a directory from the file system. According to what I found online, this can either be done with the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) or [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) classes. However, both of them live in `System.Windows.Forms`, but the compiler claims that there is no `Forms` namespace in `System.Windows`.

I have tried to add a reference through Visual Studio and I also tried adding `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` to my `.csproj`-file manually, but to no avail. Most of the questions surrounding this topic are back from the days where .NET Core was the current .NET version.

From the few up-to-date answers I found, it seems like the application has to be Windows-specific, in order to use `System.Windows.Forms` (which sounds logical). Unfortunately, my application needs to be multi-platform and also work under Linux. Is there any way I can show a dialog to select a directory under these circumstances?

Comment: WinForms and WPF are Windows only features, even in .NET6+. See [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/?view=netdesktop-6.0) or [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/overview/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Is the remainder of your app console-only? Does your application do any other UI? What choices did you make here?

Comment: @spender It's a web application. The backend is .Net 6, the frontend is angular. For reasons to lengthy to explain in a comment, the backend is run locally. That's why I'm able to (theoretically) do this.

Comment: Can you not then trigger an `<input type="file"/>` in the browser portion of your app and use that?

Comment: @spender The problem with that is that this also uploads the files in the selected directory (which can't be prevented by calling event.preventDefault()). Technically that isn't  a problem, but I feel like this would be more irritating to the user than having to input a directory manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no build-in/provided by Microsoft UI framework for C# which supports Linux. To monitor Linux support for "cross-platform" MAUI you can follow [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5801). But there are alternatives, for example - [AvaloniaUI](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) -  a quite popular UI framework for .NET which supports Linux.

Comment: Funny enough, we evaluated both those frameworks before starting this project, but didn't see a reason to use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no way to do that.

If You want to create a dialog yourself, you can use MAUI, but unfortunately the "official" version doesn't include Linux.